# Rational approximation to complex function involving arctan and sqrt

Tags: complex-analysis, approximation, rational-functions

I'm dealing with the following type of function where $\omega_a$, $\gamma$ and $a$ are parameters:
$$
f(\omega)\propto \sqrt{\omega_\textrm{a}-\omega-\textrm{i}\gamma}\; \arctan\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{\omega_\textrm{a}-\omega-\textrm{i}\gamma}}\right)
$$

Im currently thinking of ways to approximate this function by a rational function (in $\omega$). The issue I'm having is that the quantities under the square root as well as in the arctan are complex. I've really no idea how to do it - I didn't hear any functional analysis but I feel like it has to do something with analytical continuation. I would be happy about any tips how to approach the problem!

What I did first was trying to ignore that the arguments are complex-valued, so I did some Taylor expansion, Padé-approximation and such, but then the real and imaginary part of the approximant were completely different from the original function.

I've stumbled upon this representation of the arcus tanges for complex arguments (taken from wikipedia):
$$
\arctan(a+b\,\mathrm i) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll} \displaystyle
\frac12\,\left(\arctan \frac{a^2+b^2-1}{2a} + \frac\pi2\,\textrm{sgn}(a) \right)
 & \; a\neq0 \\
0
 & \; a=0,\, |b|\leq1 \\ \displaystyle
\frac\pi2\,\textrm{sgn}(b)
 & \; a=0,\, |b|>1 \\
\end{array} \right\} \\
+ \mathrm i \cdot \frac12\,\operatorname{artanh} \frac{2b}{a^2+b^2+1}
$$
But since the argument in my function $f(\omega)$ involves a square root I do have a lot of terms to the power of $\frac{1}{2}$, $\frac{3}{2}$ and so on.

Regarding the range of values of $\omega \in [\omega_L, \omega_U]$ I can say that $\omega_L<\omega_a<\omega_U$ but it is not really restricted. Typical values are: $10^{15} <\omega < 10^{16},\;\omega_a = 3\cdot 10^{15}$ and $a=5\cdot10^{7}$. With these values we have

$$
    \max_\omega \Re\left(\cfrac{a}{\sqrt{\omega_a+\omega+\textrm{i}\gamma}} \right) \approx 1.385 \qquad\qquad
    \min_\omega \Re\left(\cfrac{a}{\sqrt{\omega_a+\omega+\textrm{i}\gamma}}\right) \approx 0.625
$$

$$
    \max_\omega \Im\left(\cfrac{a}{\sqrt{\omega_a+\omega+\textrm{i}\gamma}}\right) \approx 0.0152 \qquad\qquad
    \min_\omega \Im\left(\cfrac{a}{\sqrt{\omega_a+\omega+\textrm{i}\gamma}}\right) \approx 0.0150
$$

Comment: Around what value of $\omega$ do you want to make the approximation ?

Comment: If $\left| a \right|^2  < \left| z \right|$, you have
$$
\sqrt z \arctan \left( {\frac{a}{{\sqrt z }}} \right) = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{( - 1)^n }}{{2n + 1}}\frac{{a^{2n + 1} }}{{z^n }}} 
$$
which does not involve square roots anymore.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici oh, thanks for pointing this out, I'll edit my post, the range of values of $\omega$ is crucial

Comment: @Gary how did you come up with this solution? does it apply for complex z? Thanks in every case!

Comment: @Brosch I just used the power series of $\arctan w$ about $w=0$. It converges for complex $w$, $|w|<1$.

Comment: @Gary Thats the problem, $|\omega|\nless 1$ here (see my recent edit and the range of $\omega$)

Comment: Then you can use $$
\sqrt z \arctan \left( {\frac{a}{{\sqrt z }}} \right) = \frac{\pi }{2}\sqrt z  - \sqrt z \arctan \left( {\frac{{\sqrt z }}{a}} \right) = \frac{\pi }{2}\sqrt z  - \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{( - 1)^n }}{{2n + 1}}\frac{{z^{n + 1} }}{{a^{2n + 1} }}} 
$$ for $|z|<a^2$.

Comment: I've already tried this, in fact, if i define a piecewise approximate function like this, the values around $|z|=1$ are pretty far off. There is another faster converging approximate function $\arctan(z) = 2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \cfrac{1}{2n-1}\; \cfrac{a_n(x)}{a_n^2(x)+b_n^2(x)}$ which approximates $\arctan(z)$ very well even near $|z|$ but for reasons I don't understand combined with a taylor expansion of the square root it doesn't resemble the original function well at all (I have a feeling it has to do with the fact, that my arguments are complex-valued).

Comment: You may also try this one: http://dlmf.nist.gov/4.24.E5

Comment: @Gary this one seems promising, thanks for your reasearch, I'll try it out soon.